# output is not what I expected because of operator precedence

Tags: java, operator-keyword

```
int a = 6;
int b = 5;

System.out.print(a *= a++ - (a++) * b);
```

result out -174

I thought (a++) -> 6
and following the operation ordering, 7 - (6) * 5 => -23
then a should be now 8.
so 8 *= -23 => -184 is what I thought

Please help me out step by step which was wrong and I misunderstand.

Thanks

Comment: parenthesis don't change the fact that each individual component is evaluated left-to-right.

Comment: Why would the second `a++` (the one in the parentheses) be evaluated first?

Comment: `a++` will return the original value and only then increment. So what you have above is equal to `6*(6-7*5)`

Comment: also remember there is `++a` which first increments then gives the value back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Java Language Specification section 15.7.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.1),

> The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated.

So in your case, the unparenthesised `a++` is evaluated before `(a++) * b`, which makes the right hand side of the assignment equal to `6 - 7 * 5`.  That's equal to `-29`, and multiplying `a` by `-29` gives `-174`.